# Plesk doesn't upload backups to FTP, saves locally instead

Tags: plesk

I have a weird problem with Plesk. I used to have scheduled backups saved on the server but changed that to FTP repository. The problem is that Plesk keeps saving backups on the same server and doesn't upload anything on my FTP. I could assume that there is something wrong with the FTP access but I don't get any notifications about this although I've added my email address into the scheduled backups settings. Please give me a piece of advice

Comment: i'm having the same issue, have you checked your ftp details from the server i.e. ssh to your server and try an ftp connection

Comment: weirdly for me doing an FTP backup works unless its scheduled. Is this the same for anybody else?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for days until I noticed that the /usr partition it wasn't large enough to hold the temporal backup. The issue was due to a lack of space on the /usr partition; the backups worked previously because there was enough space on /usr to hold them during the backup job, however the backup (~3.4 GB) was too large at that moment. So I added 10 extra Gb to that partition and the problem was solved.
Plesk: 11.0.9 Update #55 CentOs 6.4

Comment: How do you add extra gb? Can it be achieve via Plesk?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided Plesk version you running. 
I had similar problem, it started after upgrade to plesk version 11. Please have a look at this post; instructions provided by dischneider resolved my issue:

http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=260857

Answer (score 0):

> I could assume that there is something wrong with the FTP access

Try to perform manual backup to FTP repository.

Also check /usr/local/psa/PMM/logs/pmmcli.log for error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, your comments were helpful. The real reason was caused by a problem with connecting to FTP. That's why the backups were left on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue for those experiencing this problem is that some FTP servers will not accept transfers greater than a certain filesize. This is the case for Amazon S3, it will not accept fiels larger than 5GB on PUT. We had to use the multi-compression feature to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

As jersoncito suggested, this can happen when your /usr partition is too small to hold the data. Plesk always creates a local backup and then transfers it off to FTP. When it's successful it will delete the local backup - but when there's a problem, it will leave it local.

If you can't resize the /usr partition, you can bind mount a larger directory into the something else - say /var/temp:

```
service psa stop

mount --bind /var/tempfiles /usr/local/psa/PMM/tmp
mount --bind /var/tempfiles /usr/local/psa/tmp

service psa restart
```

There's a KB article on this subject here: http://kb.parallels.com/114415